# Visible property working inconsistently in vba

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a reset button that should hide and disable certain buttons on its form, but it's not working. I've tried applying the same `ctl.visible = false` and `ctl.enabled = false` coding to other controls (including buttons) in the same sub, and it all works - it's just for these buttons it refuses to. No errors come up, it just doesn't change either the visible or enabled properties. I've also manually changed their properties in the properties list in access, which works too. And a separate sub that enables and un-hides them works fine.

The buttons I need to hide and disable are tagged with "spin". They're dealt with at the bottom of the Reset sub below. The whole sub is provided for context, in case any of it is responsible for my issue.

```
Private Sub btnReset_Click()

Dim ctl As Control

For Each ctl In Screen.ActiveForm
If ctl.Tag Like "*lckbtn*" Then
    ctl.Enabled = True
    ctl.Visible = True
ElseIf ctl.Tag Like "*lcktxt*" Then
    ctl.Enabled = False
    ctl.Locked = True
    ctl.BackColor = RGB(236, 236, 236)
On Error Resume Next
    ctl.Value = ""
ElseIf ctl.Name = "PointsRemaining" Then
    ctl.ForeColor = RGB(140, 140, 140)
    ctl.Value = 27
    End If
If ctl.Tag Like "*array*" Then
    ctl.ForeColor = RGB(140, 140, 140)
    End If
    Next ctl
If ctl.Tag Like "*spin*" Then
    ctl.Enabled = False
    ctl.Visible = False
    End If

Array1 = 15
Array2 = 14
Array3 = 13
Array4 = 12
Array5 = 10
Array6 = 8

End Sub
```

Comment: `if like` is case sensitiv. maybe there is your problem.

Comment: the case is the same though - I specifically avoided caps in my tags for just that sort of reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

---

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub btnReset_Click()
    Dim ctl As Control

    For Each ctl In Screen.ActiveForm
        Select Case True
            Case InStr(1, ctl.Tag, "lckbtn", vbTextCompare)
                ctl.Enabled = True
                ctl.Visible = True
            Case InStr(1, ctl.Tag, "lcktxt", vbTextCompare)
                ctl.Enabled = False
                ctl.Locked = True
                ctl.BackColor = RGB(236, 236, 236)
                On Error Resume Next
                ctl.Value = ""
            Case ctl.Name = "PointsRemaining"
                ctl.ForeColor = RGB(140, 140, 140)
                ctl.Value = 27
            Case InStr(1, ctl.Tag, "array", vbTextCompare)
                ctl.ForeColor = RGB(140, 140, 140)
            Case InStr(1, ctl.Tag, "spin", vbTextCompare)
                ctl.Enabled = False
                ctl.Visible = False
        End Select
    Next ctl
    Array1 = 15
    Array2 = 14
    Array3 = 13
    Array4 = 12
    Array5 = 10
    Array6 = 8
End Sub
```

---

There are a few issues with your code

- Indentation is quite misleading
- `If ctl.Tag Like "*spin*" Then` is outside the `For` loop

  - When execution point gets to this line, `ctl` is not set (error)
  - You also have `On Error Resume Next` which hides the above error
  - `On Error Resume Next` is a procedure-level handler (not only for the following line)
- `Like`, as noted, is case sensitive (didn't get to this point yet because of the previous issue)

---

This is your code with proper indentation (it shows that the last `If` is outside the loop)

---

```
Private Sub btnReset_Click()
    Dim ctl As Control

    For Each ctl In Screen.ActiveForm
        If ctl.Tag Like "*lckbtn*" Then
            ctl.Enabled = True
            ctl.Visible = True
        ElseIf ctl.Tag Like "*lcktxt*" Then
            ctl.Enabled = False
            ctl.Locked = True
            ctl.BackColor = RGB(236, 236, 236)
On Error Resume Next
            ctl.Value = ""
        ElseIf ctl.Name = "PointsRemaining" Then
            ctl.ForeColor = RGB(140, 140, 140)
            ctl.Value = 27
        End If
        If ctl.Tag Like "*array*" Then
            ctl.ForeColor = RGB(140, 140, 140)
        End If
    Next ctl
    If ctl.Tag Like "*spin*" Then   '<-- outside of the For loop (error as ctl is not set)
        ctl.Enabled = False
        ctl.Visible = False
    End If
    Array1 = 15
    Array2 = 14
    Array3 = 13
    Array4 = 12
    Array5 = 10
    Array6 = 8
End Sub
```

---

Comment: This works. But why!? It also works if I substitute the InStr function with the original Like clause, but still use Select Case instead of If/ElseIf. 

Certainly Select Case is neater, but why wouldn't If Then work?

Comment: I added your code with proper indentation to show the main issue

Comment: Ok, same problem, different place: now the array bit doesn't work:

`Case ctl.Tag Like "*array*"
                ctl.ForeColor = RGB(140, 140, 140)`
Color stays black...
And the problem remains when I swap it over to the InStr function instead of Like, even though I've gotten rid of that error handler, as I no longer needed it.

Comment: Sure, but if this question is fixed we should close it (please accept the answer), then open a new one and provide the full code relevant to the arrays (in this question there no details related to them - not sure where they are created, re-dimmed, updated, etc)

Comment: Oh, never mind - I worked it out: only one case can apply to any specific control. the arrays are also lcktxts, and as they already fell under the previous case, they can't also be considered an extra one.

Comment: Glad you figured it out !

Comment: h-uh; last time i asked a question it made me wait a whole day before I could accept an answer.
I've fixed it all up now. Thanks for your help!